# Uint8_t Setting Itself

Tags: c, uint8t

I have something of a minor annoyance rather than a bug but I can't figure out why it's occurring. I have an array index and 2D gchar array declared like this:

```
gchar FilterArray[10][51];
static uint8_t ArrayIndex = 0;
static gchar ScanLine[9640];
```

Now, the first time I use Array Index it's somehow the value 115. I didn't set it anywhere in the code before using it. If I only print it out after I use it in the strcpy command, its' value is 115. If I print it out before the strcpy command, it's value is correct for the duration of the program.

```
while(FilterAmount != 0)
{
    g_io_channel_read_chars (source,(gchar *) ScanLine,1,&BytesRead,&GlibError);
    if(ScanLine[0] == FilterTerminator[0]) { 
        printf("Array Index: %i\n", ArrayIndex);
        if(strlen(FilterName) > 0){
            printf("Array Index: %i\n", ArrayIndex); //if I only print before, value is correct
            strcpy(FilterArray[ArrayIndex],FilterName); 
            printf("Array Index: %i\n", ArrayIndex); //if I only print after, value is incorrect
            ArrayIndex++; 
            FilterAmount--; 
            FilterName[0] = '\0'; 
        }
    }
    else {
        strcat(FilterName, ScanLine);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `strncpy()` and not `strcpy()`?

Comment: Even so, the buffer size for `strncpy` should be the size of the target buffer, not the source buffer. (Or at least the smaller of both.) 115 is the ASCII value of `s`. Is that any help?

Comment: @alk I originally used strcpy() and I thought that my issue might be with that, so I switched to strncpy() but unfortunately it made no difference.

Comment: @MOehm Oh, that is a mistake, good catch. Luckily for me it wasn't effecting me too much. That might mean something...let me look into it.

Comment: Get rid of the `strncpy()` it's seldom useful, and its use is error prone. In your case it might only make sense if a truncated result would be of any use.

Comment: How is `ScanLine` defined and initialised?

Comment: @alk Added declaration to OP and changed `strncpy`. Also updated the specific problem with more definition. `ScanLine` is never "initialized" it's only ever used as a 1 byte buffer for `g_io_channel_read_chars`

Comment: Thanks. However, as addtions mostly enhance a question, deleting things from it might make some answers and/or comments un-understandable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60016/discussion-between-scott-james-walter-and-alk).

Comment: @M Oehm  "buffer size for strncpy should be the size of the target buffer" exposes a hole in `strncpy()` usage with `strncpy(
FilterArray[ArrayIndex],FilterName, sizeof FilterArray[ArrayIndex]);`.  `FilterArray[ArrayIndex]` may end up _without_ a terminating `’\0’`.  Better to use `strncpy()` usage.  `strncpy(FilterArray[ArrayIndex],FilterName, sizeof FilterArray[ArrayIndex] - 1); FilterArray[ArrayIndex][sizeof FilterArray[ArrayIndex] – 1] = ‘\0’;`.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, `FilterName` is excessively long and `strcpy(FilterArray[ArrayIndex],FilterName)` writes beyond the end of `FilterArray` and over `ArrayIndex`. That `ArrayIndex` seems correct if printed before the `strcpy` might be because the value is kept in a register and not loaded again from the overwritten memory location.